# Querying Access With VBS, can't figure out how to include Where statement with recordset

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, ado, recordset

```
Dim connStr, objConn, getNames

connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\meandmine\Desktop\inventory.accdb"

Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

objConn.open connStr

Set rs = objConn.execute("SELECT Renewals.[Product Name], Renewals.[Expiration Date] FROM Renewals")

'While loop, loops through all available results
DO WHILE NOT rs.EOF

'add names seperated by comma to getNames
getNames = getNames + rs.Fields(0) & "," 
'move to next result before looping again
'this is important
rs.MoveNext
'continue loop
Loop

'Close connection and release objects
objConn.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing

'Return Results via MsgBox
MsgBox getNames
```

This is the code I'm trying to use and it generates all the names of the software in a MSGbox, yet doesn't show dates.

```
WHERE (((Renewals.[Expiration Date]) Between Date() And DateAdd("d",60,Date())));
```

I'm trying to use this where statement on my query, this where statement works in Access, I'm very confused.  I've been playing with this for about seven hours now. If I put it after the From part of the SQL query I still get the same old query of the name of every product.  I'm a total newb.

Answer (score 0):

`rs.Fields(0)` is only the first field in your recordset. The date is the second field which is `rs.Fields(1)`

You should do the following:

```
getNames = getNames + rs.Fields(0)  & " " & rs.Fields(1) & ","
```

Comment: So that totally worked in showing the dates =] but where would I throw in the where parameter to make it sort?  Thank you for your help =]

Comment: The `WHERE` parameter does not sort, rather filters. It would be appended to the SELECT statement. To sort you would use `ORDER BY`